# reshaping a dataframe using stack/unstack

Tags: pandas, dataframe, stack, pivot, multi-index

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['Q','A','A'], 'Fields': ['Q1','Pre','Post'],'ChildA' : [0,3,5],'ChildB' : [0,2,3]})

    ChildA  ChildB Fields Field_Type
 0       0       0     Q1          Q
 1       3       2    Pre          A
 2       5       3   Post          A
```

there's about 200 or so children in total and 50 or so questions. What I'm trying to get to is something that looks like this:

```
      Name     Question    Pre     Post
   0  ChildA   Q1          3       5
   1  ChildB   Q1          2       3
   2  ChildA   Q2          1       4
   3  ChildB   Q2          3       3
```

but I'm unsure how best to approach this,I've tried `stack` and `pivot` but both will return `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` or when it works, it isn't in a format I need, or can work towards the correct format. Closest I've got to so far is by using transpose `df2 = df1[0:3].T` which works ok as long as I take 3 rows at a time, but this seems very inefficient and I know there must be a better way using pivot or stack/unstack.

Perhaps this will involve some mutli-indexing, so I'm drawn towards `stack` since `pivot` is giving all sorts of issues such as `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional` when I would try say

```
df1.pivot(columns='Name',values=['Ben','Jack'])
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Really you have two sets of data in one dataframe.  Plus the answers do not have which question they are for

1. put an question against each answer using combination of `np.where` and `fillna()`
2. with just the answers index it so transpose makes sense
3. `stack()` the *Question* to be a column again

```
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Type' : ['Q','A','A'], 'Fields': ['Q1','Pre','Post'],'ChildA' : [0,3,5],'ChildB' : [0,2,3]})

maskq = df1["Type"]=="Q"
# need to get question against each answer
df1 = (df1
 .assign(Question=lambda x: np.where(x["Type"]=="Q", x["Fields"], np.nan))
 .assign(Question=lambda x: x["Question"].fillna(method="ffill"))
)
# now take just questions and organise as required
df1 = df1.loc[~maskq, [c for c in df1.columns if c!="Type"]].set_index(["Fields","Question"]).T.stack()
```

**output**

```
Fields           Post  Pre
       Question           
ChildA Q1           5    3
ChildB Q1           3    2
```